# Oracle Database Express Edition (XE) 18c no ejecuta correctamente consutas

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

Cuando inserto un registro, se inserta y lo compruebo con COUNT.

Pero al cerrar el sql*plus, y abrirlo nuevamente, no esta el registro.

[image: sesion SQL*plus]

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Como pregunta deja mucho que desear.. aunque lo primero que preguntaria es, estas haciendo el commit despues del insert?

Answer (score 1):

En SQL*Plus, todo comando *DML* que ejecutes lo hará, por defecto, en el contexto de una transacción manual, es decir, tienes que terminar la transacción *a mano* lanzando una sentencia `commit` o `rollback`.

De otra forma los cambios que hayas hecho, no se verán reflejados luego de terminada la sesión, que es lo que ocurre, por ejemplo, cuando cierras la herramienta, pero también ocurriría si cambias de usuario o simplemente te desconectas de la base de datos.

En mi opinión, este comportamiento es el mejor. Puedo suponer que eres nuevo en el mundo de bases de datos o vienes de utilizar herramientas de otros fabricantes, pero es fácil acostumbrarse a la idea, simplemente, luego de evaluar que los resultados de tus sentencias son los esperados, lanzar:

```
SQL>commit;
```

Si quieres cambiar este comportamiento, cosa que no es para nada recomendada, puedes hacerlo estableciendo a `ON` o `IMMEDIATE` la configuración `AUTOCOMMIT` del SQL*Plus:

```
SQL>set autocommit immediate;
```

Dado que la configuración por defecto es `OFF`, tendrás que hacer esto cada vez que inicies SQL*Plus, o bien cambiar tu [script de inicialización](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10500_01/server.920/a90842/ch3.htm) (login) para que este cambio surta efecto siempre.